Nuxt3 Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'baseURL')
In my Nuxt3-Vue3-Vuetify3 website, only in production mode the site is not initialised sometimes on the initial pageload. It is not always happening, but when it happens, I get this error message from one of the auto-generated Nuxt files:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'baseURL')

The error message is pointing to one of the minified files, to a row like this:
 Y0 = ()=>Is.baseUR

I have tried to reproduce the error in local but it never happens there, so I'm not sure that where is it coming from, none of my components includes "baseURL" property anywhere. Does anyone know how to figure out the source of the error and how to fix it?

Is is sometimes undefined. Sometimes it resolves fast enough and sometimes not. You should fail-safe the async operation due to network speed concerns.

Do you have a suggestion, how can i fail-safe the async operation to achieve this? Considering that I'm using nuxt-booster (but this error happened before using that too)

I do not know what nuxt-booster is but since you had this error before, I guess it's unrelated. As for a suggestion, I'd need some code to find what's wrong. Hard to guess where the issue is coming from based on 1 line of pseudo-code.

From the minified code I think I could figure out that the problem is related to the runtimeconfig:
This is how the minified version looks like where I have the error message:
Is = K0().app
, Y0 = ()=>Is.baseURL
, q0 = ()=>Is.buildAssetsDir
I think this most probably relates to runTimeConfig:
interface RuntimeConfig {
app: {
baseURL: string,
  buildAssetsDir: string,

  cdnURL: string,

},
}
Does this help?
Oh, and this is Nuxt booster: https://basics.github.io/nuxt-booster/

Yeah, Nuxt booster is not the issue at all. As for the code, why are looking at the minified code? Try to debug it in dev.

The problem is that in dev this bug literally never happens :(

Build it for production and run it locally. Then try to run some network bottlenecks thanks to the devtools, which might trigger it. Where do you host it?

Production build on local also never reproduces this error. The site is hosted on azure

Try to host it on Netlfy for debugging purposes (know if it's a platform issue or not).

If someone is here for the solution, let me add it, because it has finally been resolved. Nuxt3 had some conflict with the Cookiebot script added in the head section of the config file. I've changed it's async attribute to false and it resolved the problem ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Feel free to post an answer yes.

If someone is here for the solution, let me add it, because it has finally been resolved. Nuxt3 had some conflict with the Cookiebot script added in the head section of the config file. I've changed it's async attribute to false and it resolved the problem ¯_(ツ)_/¯
